# Dynamic programming and Module

Tags: functions, memoization

In the following example of the dynamic programming, why does f[n] is written at the end of the Module?

```
fib[n_] :=
 Module[{f},
  f[1] = f[2] = 1;
  f[i_] := f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2];
  f[n]
  ]
```

Further f[n] is protected? Why f[n] is not written at the end of the programing. Thanks.

Example:
In[6]:= fib[5]

Out[6]= 5

In[7]:= f[5]

Out[7]= f[5]

Comment: `f` is defined as local to the `Module` so it cannot be seen outside the `Module`

Comment: Change `f[n]` to `"f[not]"` to see what is returned from the module. I looked into the `Details` section to see if there was some guidance on what is returned from the `Module`.  It can surely be added, if it is not already there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

#### Outline of sections below

(See summary section below for a shorter answer)

*Feel free to skip around as the sections are somewhat independent*

- **1) Experiment to see what Mathematica is doing.**

**Content:** Showing that the `f` in `Module` is actually something like `f$6729`.

- **2) Why changing the variable inside `Module` is important.**

**Content:** A common example, see references for more scenarios.

- **3) Somewhat fun example.**

**Content :** Using `Module` to prevent index clashes when multiplying sums.

- **4) Can we trick `Module` ?**

**Content :** `Module` supposedly works by incrementing `$ModuleNumber`. Can we use `$ModuleNumber` and maybe `Block` to trick `Module` into reproducing the same local variable twice ?

- **5) Why localize a function when storing values ?**

**Content**  How could the local function in the `Module` of the example from the question be useful ?

- **References**

**Content** 2 references. The first to an answer that distinguishes `Module`, `With` and `Block` to have a better idea of the design choice for `Module`. The second is a tech note for `Module` in the documentation that has a discussion on local variables and in particular `Module`.

#### Summary of the discussion below

- The `f` that is written inside the module is not the `f` that Mathematica sees. Mathematica sees something similar to the output of `Unique[f]` which will be something like `f$6729` but possibly with different numbers. That is used to ensure that the `f` inside the module is different than an `f` that is outside the module.
- The local function and `Module` in the example given is useful as it has the attribute `Temporary` which means that, in the example given, the information that it has will be erased once the computation is over. This can be useful for problems that require using a lot of memory. That method has the drawback however of recomputing everything each time `fib` is called as the temporary storage of values in the definition of `f` is lost at the end of the computation.

---

#### 1) Experiment to see what Mathematica is doing.

To see what Mathematica is doing let's consider a "functional" `fib2` where `fib2` outputs a function generating the `fib` sequence rather than a number:

```
fib2 := Module[{f}, f[1] = f[2] = 1;
f[i_] := f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2];
f]
```

Why would you do that ? Well, we can see what is `f` rather than the output of `f` evaluated on an integer. In the last section before the references we will see this is one of the worst choices to make in terms of memory and time efficiency.

First, we can test that the function still works:

```
fib2[8]
```

Out: `(* 21 *)`

If we use the `fib` in your question:

```
fib[n_] := Module[{f}, f[1] = f[2] = 1;
f[i_] := f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2];
f[n]]
```

we find the same result:

```
fib[8]
```

Out:  `(* 21 *)`

Ok, now let's see what Mathematica was hiding by outputting `f` directly. A possible expectation is that `fib2` will output `f`, lets check:

```
fib2

 (* f$6778 *)
```

As mentioned in the summary `f` inside a module is not `f` but `f` plus random looking numbers.

#### 2) Why changing the variable inside `Module` is important.

Consider a very long project where on the 3rd cell there is:

```
b=4
```

then on the 42nd cell there is

```
r[x]:=Module[{b},b=0;Do[b=b^2+1,5];b]
```

If the `b` inside the `Module` was not different than the `b` outside then the value of the initial `b` at line 3 would be lost after setting `b=0` inside `Module`.

#### 3) Somewhat fun example.

There is a tensor manipulation package that uses `Module` to ensure that the indices between tensors are different when they are multiplied. For example, consider a Mathematica function that writes the expansion of the product of two sums :

$$\sum_i{a_i}\sum_i{b_i}=\sum_{i,j}{a_i b_j}$$

A first approach might be to encode:

$$\sum{a_i}$$ as

```
sum[a[i]]
```

then maybe define a sum product function like this:

```
sumprod[prodsum_] := prodsum /. sum[x_] :> x // sum
```

test:

```
sum[a[i]]*sum[b[i]] // sumprod
```

Out: `(* sum[a[i] b[i]] *)`

That is almost what we would like but it should be something like `sum[a[i] b[j]]` or `sum[a[r] b[s]]` the indices do not matter as they are summed over. A possible solution might be:

```
sumprodgood[prodsum_] := prodsum /. sum[x_] :> Module[{i}, Head[x][i]] // sum

sum[a[i]]*sum[b[i]] // sumprodgood
```

Out: `(* sum[a[i$8662] b[i$8663]] *)`

The indices might not look nice but at least the two indices are different. Alternatively one could use `Unique`

```
sumprodgoodunique[prodsum_] := 
prodsum /. sum[x_] :> Head[x][Unique@i] // sum
```

test:

```
sum[a[i]]*sum[b[i]] // sumprodgoodunique
```

Out: `(* sum[a[i$8665] b[i$8666]] *)`

Notice that the indices are not the same as with `sumprodgood` which means that indeed each instance of `i` in a `Module` or in `Unique` has a different output.

#### 4) Can we trick `Module` ?

TL;DR: I did not find any way to make `Module[{x},x]` output the same result twice even after changing `$ModuleNumber` inside and outside `Block`

The discussion above explained that `Module[{x},x]` gives a different x each time. How does it do that ?

According to the documentation on `Module`

> Module creates a symbol with name `xxx$nnn` to represent a local variable with name `xxx`. The number `nnn` is the current value of `$ModuleNumber`.
> The value of `$ModuleNumber` is incremented every time any module is used.

If we then check the documentation on `$ModuleNumber` we have the example:

```
{$ModuleNumber, Module[{x}, x], $ModuleNumber}
```

Out: `(* {14562, x$14562, 14563} *)` (you will probably see different numbers)

So it seems that basically at the end of each `Module` call the `$ModuleNumber` is increased by 1. That sounds like it is simple to trick so that `Module` gives the same result twice. For example,

```
$ModuleNumber = 1;
xa = Module[{x}, x]
$ModuleNumber = 1;
xb = Module[{x}, x];
{xa, xb}
```

Out: `(* {x$1, x$2} *)`

So it seems that `Module` does more. It ensures that there is no other name in Names["x$*"] with the the same name as what it was told to output. Outside of these potential cases, it does do what is requested :

```
$ModuleNumber = 1;
ya = Module[{y}, y]
$ModuleNumber = 3;
yb = Module[{y}, y];
{ya, yb}
```

Out:  `(* {y$1, y$3} *)`

One can also use `Block` to reset global constants to another value within the body of the block, for example:

```
$ModuleNumber = 1; {{$ModuleNumber, Module[{w}, w], 
  Unique[w], $ModuleNumber}, 
 Block[{$ModuleNumber = 5}, {$ModuleNumber, Module[{w}, w], 
   Unique[w], $ModuleNumber}]}
```

Out: `(* {{1, w$1, w$2, 3}, {5, w$5, w$6, 7}} *)`

Can one use `Block` to obtain the same output twice from `Module` ?

```
$ModuleNumber = 1; {{$ModuleNumber, Module[{u}, u], 
  Unique[u], $ModuleNumber}, 
 Block[{$ModuleNumber = 1}, {$ModuleNumber, Module[{u}, u], 
   Unique[u], $ModuleNumber}]}
```

Out: `(* {{1, u$1, u$2, 3}, {1, u$3, u$4, 5}} *)`

`Module` is able to ensure that the the output from a local variable is never the same.

Ok, one last try.

```
Module[{x}, Print[x]; Module[{x}, Print[x]]]
```

The x variable in the second `Module` is highlighted in a different color in Mathematica. Hovering over the x variable, Mathematica shows a warning that a Nested `Module` could lead to an error. The first `Print` outputs `x$38` and the second outputs `x$39`.

#### 5) Why localize a function when storing values ?

TL;DR: The purpose of the `Module` and the local function in `fib` is to erase the values stored during a computation once the computation is over. The reason it erases that information is because local variables in `Module` have the attribute `Temporary` which means they are removed once they are no longer needed.

This section can be read independently from the other sections.

Let's compare the `fib` in the question with the more usual fib function that does not use a local function:

```
fib3[1] = fib3[2] = 1;
fib3[i_] := fib3[i] = fib3[i - 1] + fib3[i - 2];
```

We can check that `fib` and `fib3` have the same values and the timing is about the same when evaluating `fib[10^3]` for example. However, `fib3` stores the values of `fib3[i]` for all `i` between `1` and `10^3` whereas `fib` does not. The reason why `fib` does not is because the information about the computation was stored in the `DownValues` of the local variable `f` and not `fib`.

That statement can be checked by considering:

```
fibcheck[n_] := Module[{g, f}, f[1] = f[2] = 1;
f[i_] := f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2];
g = f[n];
Print[DownValues[f]]; g]
```

and then evaluating

```
fibcheck[5]
```

and checking

```
DownValues[fibcheck]//Length
```

Out;  `(* 1 *)`

After evaluating `fib3` on 10^3 one can check that

```
DownValues[fib3] // Length
```

Out  `(* 1001 *)`

Thus it seems like `fib` uses less memory than `fib3` but one might argue that the memory is stored in the local variable `f`.
However, local variables in `Module` have attribute `Temporary` and the `DownValues` of `f` are lost after the evaluation was completed.

This is not the case with `fib2` that outputs the local function. That can be checked by evaluating `fib2[10^3]`, looking for the last element in the list given by `Names["f*"]`, and evaluating the `Length` of the `DownValues` of this element. Finally to be sure that `fib` is not using any extra memory one can check  `MemoryInUse[]` before and after in each case of `fib`,`fib2` and `fib3`:
First we ensure that Mathematica retains all the calculations (that is the default behavior by some people change this in their init.m file)

```
$HistoryLength = Infinity;
```

then we evaluate

```
mem = MemoryInUse[];
fib[10^3];
Print[MemoryInUse[] - mem];
mem = MemoryInUse[];
fib2[10^3];
Print[MemoryInUse[] - mem];
mem = MemoryInUse[];
fib3[10^3];
Print[MemoryInUse[] - mem];
```

Out: `(* 2960 221048 218752 *)`

It is clear that `fib` uses the least amount of memory and outputting the local function looses the memory efficiency. Evaluating the above sequence a second time leads to the output:

Out: `(* 3088 220088 1728 *)`

Only `fib2` added a significant amount of memory. That is because it saved all the information from the computation but in a new local function that will note even be used. Moreover, checking `AbsoluteTiming` shows that the timing is very small upon re-evaluation except for `fib2` that computes everything again.

Hence, the function `fib2` that outputs the local function is neither memory efficient nor time efficient.

So is `fib` better than the usual `fib3` ? That depends on whether memory is important. If the usual `fib3` requires too much memory then one might want to use `fib`. The drawback is that since `fib` does not permanently store all of the information from prior calculations, `fib` will re-evaluate the entire computation each time whereas the usual `fib3` will use prior computations. Thus it is a question of time vs memory.

### References

- I personally like this answer on stack exchange in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/86543) link. It refers to the differences between `Module`, `Block` and `With` but the other answers might be useful too.
- A tech note in the documentation that offers an [explanation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html#22619) on how `Module` (and `Block`) works and some examples of its use.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Further, how about two or more than two local variables inside the module. Can we define all those local variables at the end to save memory for all the locals. e.g. Module[{f,g}, function definitions of f and g ;  f, g]

Comment: Hi, do not worry about the edit I did not add anything to the content of the text I  just added an outline to make it easier to skip around the sections  and I changed some of the titles.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, if you output the function directly then you loose both memory and time efficiency. You have to evaluate the local functions on the arguments of the global function that define them (like in the original `fib` in your question) rather than output the local functions in the `Module` (like in `fib2`).

Comment: The reason is that the memory storage for the computation is discarded only if Mathematica sees that the functions themselves (not the functions evaluated on numbers) are not needed (that is what the `Temporary` attribute does in the `Module`). If you output the functions then they are needed and all of the information is kept in a new local function every time the function is evaluated.

Comment: So a more efficient example would be `h[x_]:=Module[{f,g}, function definitions of f and g ; {f[x], g[x]}]` rather than the one mentioned `Module[{f,g}, function definitions of f and g ; {f, g}]` (I added the curly braces to output the list as I guess that is what you wanted)

Comment: Then, if the functions are evaluated on the arguments of the global variable (h in the comment above) then, yes all of the variables in `Module` have attribute Temporary so they will be removed once they are no longer needed. You can see that with `Module[{a, b}, a = 1; b = 5;   Print[{{Hold[a], Attributes[a]}, {Hold[b], Attributes[b]}}];   Nest[Sqrt, a + b, 3]]` that shows the attributes of the two local variables. You can then check `Names["b$*"]` to see that there are no local variables.

Comment: If you look at `Names["b*"]` you will see there is a b but it does not have the expected type of name for a local variable like b$.. and If you look at `Definition[b]` there is nothing there.

Comment: **That said** managing the memory using local variables like that is rather advanced. In general you will not have that issue and you can just use Mathematica without thinking about that. So basically the important part of the answer is more how `Module` changes the names of variables inside it rather than the memory management part.

Comment: Very well explained! Thanks.